formula that will return the Company Account number for the invoice number
In the screen shot provided the company account numbers are in column B, the invoice numbers are in Column D. I need a formula that will return the Company identifier when the Invoice number is referenced.
I have tried Index and VLOOKUP, I just don't think I am writing the formulas correctly, this report is 44 pages long with multiple accounts listed.
Screenshot
